# Redirection 302 after login in Java when status 200 in other langs

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I found code on Python and C# that I shoud translate to Java. But when I try to login it show request code 302. In POST in browser it also 302. Can you, please, say what is wrong?

My code:

```
public class Auth {
String login, passwd;
public Auth(String login, String passwd) throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(login, passwd));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Auth("login@mail.ru", "passwd");
  }
}
```

Code for translate (Python):

```
def __recreate_token(self):
    loginResponse = self.session.post("https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth",
                                      data={
                                          "page": "http://cloud.mail.ru/",
                                          "Login": self.login,
                                          "Password": self.password
                                      },verify=False
                                      )
if loginResponse.status_code == requests.codes.ok and loginResponse.history:
...
```

And C#:

```
...
string reqString = string.Format("Login={0}&Domain={1}&Password={2}", this.LoginName, ConstSettings.Domain, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.Password));
byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/cgi-bin/auth", ConstSettings.AuthDomen));
        request.Proxy = this.Proxy;
        request.CookieContainer = this.Cookies;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = ConstSettings.DefaultRequestType;
        request.Accept = ConstSettings.DefaultAcceptType;
        request.UserAgent = ConstSettings.UserAgent;
        var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, asyncResult => request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult), null);
        return await await task.ContinueWith(async (t) =>
         {
             using (var s = t.Result)
             {
                 s.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
                 using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                 {
                     if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                     {
                         throw new Exception();}
...
```

Comment: In C# you're setting 3 name/value pairs, named `"Login"`, `"Domain"`, and `"Password"`. In Python you're setting 3 name/value pairs, named `"Login"`, `"page"`, and `"Password"`, so not even the same values. In Java you're setting **1** *(ONE!)* name/value pair, named whatever is in the `login` variable. Why would you think that's even close to the same thing?

Comment: @Andreas, I already tried like in Python and C# but result is 302 and warnings/errors. This variant from Java tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "http://cloud.mail.ru/"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", login));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", passwd));
```

instead of

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(login, passwd));
```

Comment: I already tried this but it show many warnings about cookie and 302 request (

Comment: Screen of the output if it is interesting: [link](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/89Go/FNvoLWGat)